# Why does SetBasePath not work in .NET Core 3.1? I've tried adding nuget packages, but it doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net-core

> Error CS1061
> 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'SetBasePath' and no accessible extension method 'SetBasePath' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RGAj.png)

I've installed these packages:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
```

The code is working in .NET Core 2.2 but not in .NET Core 3.1.

Code is here:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Core.Logic.Mappers
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                                                         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                                                                         .Build();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, after couple days I found solution:

I have multiple-projects in my solution, so I was installing

```
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json;
```

to other project. Noobie :D

Comment: thanks that helped! don't forget to mark your answer as correct. This might help others as well.